# Google maps API Map error: go.co/staticmaperror

Tags: node.js, google-maps

everyone, I am trying to analyse the tweets about cats from Australia and it is all going well but some people are putting their location as: "NoWhere", "Mars" and other places, so I have been using google maps to confirm that the places are real and after many hours it worked perfectly, but when I analyze more than 50 tweets, the API gives me an image with API error and I can't find the problem

one of the things that people suggested that my link is over 2000 characters long but when I put the request in online tools, all of them say that my link is only 883 characters long. Any advice will be greatly appreciated:

Here are the locations I have been trying to make a map for:
([http://i.imgur.com/ckh6hcN.png](https://i.imgur.com/ckh6hcN.png))

and here is the map I get:
([http://i.imgur.com/Bl71jFC.png](https://i.imgur.com/Bl71jFC.png))

and here is the request link

https:// maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Australia&zoom=4&size=500x400&markers=Scarborough%20WA%206019%2C%20Australia&markers=Wandering%20WA%206308%2C%20Australia&markers=Australia&markers=West%20Coast%20TAS%207321%2C%20Australia&markers=Perth%20WA%2C%20Australia&markers=Baldivis%20WA%206171%2C%20Australia&markers=South%20Australia%2C%20Australia&markers=Alice%20Springs%20NT%200870%2C%20Australia&markers=a%2F11%20Talavera%20Rd%2C%20Macquarie%20Park%20NSW%202113%2C%20Australia&markers=Western%20Australia%2C%20Australia&markers=Boddington%20WA%206390%2C%20Australia&markers=Bunbury%20WA%206230%2C%20Australia&markers=Waroona%20WA%206215%2C%20Australia&markers=Melbourne%20VIC%2C%20Australia&markers=Geraldton%20WA%206530%2C%20Australia&markers=Osborne%20Park%20WA%206017%2C%20Australia&markers=Mandurah%20WA%2C%20Australia&key=[key]

These addresses are not invalid because I filtered them with google maps geocode to validate them.

note: I have separated the https in the request link because StackOverflow doesn't allow more than 2 links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to Google in twitter they informed me that there is nothing wrong in my link, is just that we are not allowed to request more than 15 markers and I am requesting 17.

Hope this helped someone :)